# Find a specific series with a known series

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let $\sum a_n$ be a convergent, positive series. Show that there exists a a convergent, positive series $\sum b_n$ such that $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_n}{b_n}=0.$$

Do $$b_n=\sqrt{a_n+a_{n+1}+\cdots}$$ verifies? I have no idea.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, $b_n=\sqrt{r_{n-1}}-\sqrt{r_n}$ with $r_n=a_{n+1}+a_{n+2}+\cdots$ verifies.

Comment: $$b_n=\sqrt{a_n+a_{n+1}+\ldots}-\sqrt{a_{n+1}+\ldots}=\frac{a_n}{\sqrt{a_n+ \ldots }+\sqrt{a_{n+1}+\ldots }}$$ Why does $\;\sum b_n\;$ converges?

Comment: @Timbuc This is easy, $\sqrt{r_1}-\sqrt{r_2}+\sqrt{r_2}-\sqrt{r_3}+\cdots$.